# What/Who is this Blue Dragon? And why is it in Orgimmar?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I was flying through Orgrimmar when I saw this blue dragon, hovering over the city.

Here is a screen shot:
[image]

It kind of looks as though it is creating a blue version of The Matrix there..

Why is/was it there, and what is/was it doing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Though I'm not into WoW, it looks like somebody acquired the legendary staff [Dragonwrath, Tarecgosa's Rest](http://wowpedia.org/Dragonwrath,_Tarecgosa%27s_Rest).

According to wowpedia:

> Once the staff is completed, Blue Drakes will appear hovering above Stormwind and Orgrimmar.

These images both look similar, from [mmochampion.org](http://www.mmo-champion.com/content/2410-World-First-Dragonwrath-Legendary-Staff-Patch-4.2-Hotfixes-August-10):

[image: Dragonwrath1]

[image: Dragonwrath2]
<sub>(source: [mmo-champion.com](http://media.mmo-champion.com/images/news/2011/august/siizstaff1.jpg))</sub>

Comment: And here is a bit of lore on [Tarecgosa](http://wowpedia.org/Tarecgosa) if you're interested?